# How to convert recorded sound into animals or robot voice?

Tags: coronasdk

I recorded the human voice and want to convert it into animal's or robot's voice just like talking tom does. Is there any way to do operation on the recorded sound in corona? Or is there any way to use the java codes?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native libraries (AKA java codes) with the Corona Enterprise Edition.